# Using Observable Timer for making clocking system

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, observable

I am using **rxjs/Rx** in angular 2 to create a clock and making lap and Sprint time laps from it.
The Code block is as follows:
**HTML:** (app.component.html)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h2>Lap Time</h2>
                <ul *ngFor="let lTime of lapTimes">
                    <li>{{lTime}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h2>Sprint Time</h2>
                <ul *ngFor="let sTime of sprintTimes">
                    <li>{{sTime}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <h1>Current Time: {{timeNow}}</h1>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-default" (click)="onStart()">Start Timer</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-default" (click)="onLoop()">Sprint and Lap</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-default" (click)="onStop()">Stop Timer</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TypeScript:** (app.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

sprintTimes: number[] = [0];
lapTimes: number[] = [0];
timeNow: number = 0;
timer: Observable<any> = Observable.timer(0, 1000);
subs: Subscription;

onStart () {
  this.subs = this.timer.subscribe((value) => {
    this.tickerFunc();
  });
  // this.onLoop();
}

onLoop () {
  this.onLap();
  this.onSprint();
}

onSprint () {
  this.sprintTimes.push(this.timeNow);
}

onLap () {
  this.lapTimes.push(this.timeNow - this.sprintTimes[this.sprintTimes.length - 1]);
}

onStop () {
  this.subs.unsubscribe();
}

tickerFunc () {
  this.timeNow++;
}

}
```

This is allowing me to create a clocking functionality. But the **Rxjs/Rx** is insufficiently documented (Its hard for me to understand it via its documentation only).
Is there any better way to do the work I'm doing here in angular? (The main purpose of mine here is: I want to conduct a online exam/ mock test.)
When I'm pressing the Start Clock Button Twice, my clock is ticking as twice as fast. (I don't understand this behavior)
Is there any other third part tool to make this easier?

Sorry that my Type Script code is not properly Indented, I'm finding it hard to use the text editor. And also this is not a place to do homework.

Answer (score 0):

> When I'm pressing the Start Clock Button Twice, my clock is ticking as twice as fast. (I don't understand this behavior)

Well, when you click this button, you execute that code:

```
this.subs = this.timer.subscribe((value) => {
  this.tickerFunc();
});
```

So, every time you click that button, you start a new timer, and every time the timer emits an event (i.e. every second), you execute

```
tickerFunc () {
  this.timeNow++;
}
```

So, if you click the button once, you increment `this.timeNow` every time the timer emits, i.e. every second.

If you click it a second time, you increment it every time the first timer emits, and every time the second timer emits. So, twice per second.

It seems you just shouldn't start a timer if it's already started. So, disable the button if the timer is already started.

Comment: I'm new to angular, so i needed review if what I'm doing is correct.
Also is there any better documentation of Rxjs?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call **unsubscribe** to stop previous timer.

```js
onStart () {
  if (this.subs) {
    this.subs.unsubscribe(); // Stop previous timer
  }
  this.subs = this.timer.subscribe((value) => {
    this.tickerFunc();
  });
  // this.onLoop();
}
```